# glUseProgram doesn't work in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, opengl-es, shader

when I use `glUseProgram`  set a prgram , then check the current program by `glGetIntegerv(GL_CURRENT_PROGRAM, &pid)`, but the `pid` returns `0`. So I cannot use this shader. The shader is compiled and linked OK.

the code :

```
[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context1];
 glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, Framebuffer1);

//there have many render option use shader1;
//and the shader1 is work normal.
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER,Renderbuffer1);
[context1 presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
glFlush();

[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context2];
 glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, Framebuffer2);

//than gluseprogram(shader1) , 
//check current shader return 0;
//but no glError
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER,Renderbuffer2);
[context2 presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
```

Why I cannot set shader again?

Answer (score 3):

You are using 2 GL contexts, and shader1 was probably compiled and linked in context1, so that's why it works. You need to share it (using some platform specific API) to be able to use it in another context (like context2), you cannot just use it without explicitly telling the API to share it with another context.

That's why it doesn't work.

Another option is to compile and link the shader in both contexts.

Comment: In ios I think just use EAGLContext* context2 = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:context1.API sharegroup:context1.sharegroup]; ,,, and two context will use same sharegroup.  I use gluseprogram(0) before second , and can success render .I do not know why?

Answer (score 1):

As Matias said, you're most likely creating the shader in a separate context than the context you're trying to use it with. To fix it, context2 should be created with context1's sharegroup:

```
EAGLContext* context2 = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:context1.API sharegroup:context1.sharegroup];
```

And after you create shader1 (with context1 being the current context), make sure to call glFlush() before switching to context2 so that the contexts' changed/created resources are synchronized (ie, the creation of shader1).